# Final trigger that ended the Age of Gods(FS/N), World binding anchors beside Rhongomyniad

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-series

So I am helping with providing ideas and checking for plotholes on FFN. The writer I am helping is planning on reintorducing the Age of Gods during the 5th Grail War so I need to know the original trigger that led to the end of the first one. I know that the barrier that seperates the Reverse side of the world where the gods/divine spirits and the general more OP beings of the Fate series reside is being maintained due to the exsistence of the real Rhongomyniad as a pillar of light that acts like an Anchor. Also are there any other anchors beside Rhongomyniad, if yes than what are they?

Answer (score 2):

> so I need to know the original trigger that led to the end of the first one

As indicated on the wikia under [World > History > Age of Gods](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/World#Age_of_Gods) the transition of the Age of Gods (genesis) to the Age of Man (0AD) came in 3 phases

- **Deterioration**

  - the Umbral Star passed by Earth allowing Sefar to invade in 12,000 BC, killing most sentient life, a large number of gods and plundering the vast majority of data from the Moon Cell
- **Separation**

  - the weakened gods tried to create a link between them and humans by creating Gilgamesh, who ultimately rebelled and encouraged the complete separation of the gods and the humans
  - the gods ended up loosing their powers and became Divine Spirits
  - the decline of Mystery (which is how the world operated back then) is attributed to the demise of the King of Magic, Solomon
- **Trigger**

  - in 700 BC, there is some unknown Trigger that caused the end of the Age of Gods (this has yet to be revealed)

so while the trigger to the very end of the age is not yet know it was probably some event which accelerated the age's end, however we can point to the fact that the Gods lost alot of power in the world after Sefar's invasion which lead to their downfall.

the page also lists an **Age of Fairies** which looks to be in between the **Age of Gods** and **Age of Man** but there is little information on this aside from the fact it has already ended, however given it's position between the 2 on the World page we might have a hint on when the **Age of Fairies** on the [Rhongomyniad](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Rhongomyniad) page

> Being the "king" that stood at the final moments of illusion and the Age of Gods, King Arthur possesses this Holy Lance that conceals such a tremendous power.

given that Vivian (the Lady of the Lake who gave Arthur/Arturia Excalibur) is a fairy we could speculate that Arthur's/Arturia's rule and legend is during the Age of Fairies

---

> Also are there any other anchors beside Rhongomyniad, if yes than what are they?

according to the wikia page on the [Reverse Side of the World](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Reverse_Side_of_the_World) there may be

> Rhongomyniad is one of the "anchors" that fasten the planet together to ensure that the world of humans on the outermost layer of the world can't be destroyed by those on the Reverse Side who wish to reenact the Age of Gods.

Source: [Reverse Side of the World (2nd Paragraph)](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Reverse_Side_of_the_World)

the use of the wording *one of the "anchors"* suggests to be there are more. however currently we don't know what the other anchors are or what form they take (or even if they are wielded in the world like Rhongomyniad with Arthur/Arturia and Grey)

Comment: in regards to possible anchors, i would not be surprised if down the road Ea is revealed to be an Anchor given the name of it's attack *Enuma Elish: The Star of Creation that Split Heaven and Earth*

Comment: Yeah, heaven is used to mention the Reverse Side of the World at times.

Comment: For what it's worth, 700 B.C. is about the time that the Etruscans rise to supremacy, who would later go on to be (integrated by) the Romans. These would displace Grecian theology with the (similar) Roman theology, and would rapidly advance technologically. Of course this "trigger" might not have been something as metaphysical as society turning away from the old gods and towards technology over magic, but it seems a nice thought at least.